# Create 2d dataframes from 3d dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following structure. `prices["Close"]["AAPL"] = series; prices["Open"]["AAPL"] = series; prices["Close"]["MSFT"] = series; prices["Open"]["MSFT"] = series`.

I want the end result to be a dataframe for each ticker so the one dataframe becomes a dataframe for each ticker with the structure `prices["Close"] = series; prices["Open"] = series`. What would be a good way to convert dataframe?

Comment: search for `xs` in Pandas documentation.

Comment: Just now, I tried `xs` with a few inputs and got KeyError. Can you post more code? I think that's relevant for index. Here, `Close` is a column of `prices`, then `prices["Close"]` is a dataframe with `MSFT` and `AAPL` columns.

Comment: `prices.xs('MSFT', axis=1, level=1)`?

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I got some progress with `prices.xs([("Close", ticker)], axis=1)` then realized need to rename columns.